# Unrecognized option: -XLoggc:

Tags: garbage-collection, java

Does OpenJDK does not support the `-XLoggc` flag? What equivalent flags can I use? Where are the flags for OpenJDK documented?

```
$ cat Hello.java
public class Hello {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
}
$ javac Hello.java
$ java -XLoggc:gc.log Hello
Unrecognized option: -XLoggc:gc.log
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_147-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.0pre) (7~b147-2.0~pre6-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flag is `-Xloggc` with lower-case "l".